# 'ChangeTracker' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this C# code which use Entity Framework Core 5 which works

```
using (var context = new MyContext(_options))
{
    context.ChangeTracker.Clear();                
    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    context.FileLogs.AddRange(fileLogs);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

But after I downgrade it to Entity Framework Core 3.1.9, `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` has syntax error. The error message is:

> 'ChangeTracker' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no
> accessible extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ChangeTracker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)

What is the solution to do the same for Entity Framework Core 3?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0)

Comment: Yeah, I know. What is the solution to do the same for Entity Framework Core 3?

Comment: Quote from the page above: "Applies to: Entity Framework Core, Version 5.0" only

Comment: You can see from the git history that `.Clear()` method was implemented in version 5. [https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/ebc00e330ad60436c3002fac539cf3a3b42687ef#diff-c461c8d8e72b4c9156a658c6bdda17f1112830d8da6a4273125a2755e45cbaf5](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/ebc00e330ad60436c3002fac539cf3a3b42687ef#diff-c461c8d8e72b4c9156a658c6bdda17f1112830d8da6a4273125a2755e45cbaf5)